# How could I force minor number allocation for SAN on linux?

Tags: linux, device, linux-device-driver, san

I've got a cluster both attached to a SAN (using multipath on linux), using RAW devices for ORACLE.

When each box boot they pick up differant minor number (I guess it's first come first serve), seems to be random allocation, not sure I need to find a way to force it. (Used to love my solaris box...). 
Therefore ORACLE is using minor number and failover will just mean loosing all the data!

How could I force minor number allocation for SAN on linux?

Comment: “Too many variables still”: Can you show the `ls -l` entry of a device? I just want to see which major,minor **all** the devices in question currently get, so as to narrow down the answerspace.

Comment: for all dev in /dev/mapper, major remain the same (253) and minor change for each device 3, 20, 34, 55 etc... but at the next reboot or the other node the number will be differante.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up `user_friendly_names yes` stanza in your multipath.conf file and enumerate all multipath devices on both nodes of your Oracle cluster:

```
multipaths {
        multipath {
                # LUN 123 on your array
                alias   ora01
                wwid    36006abcdefabcdef0123456789abcdef1
        }
}
```

Give to Oracle ASM the paths to customized names of your disks (`/dev/mapper/ora01` in this example) and both cluster nodes will see the same disk with very same name.

`wwid` begins with `3` followed by WWN of your SAN disk (refer to documentation of your SAN vendor how to get these numbers...)